# Adding numbers results in strange result - e.g. "90.005.25"

Tags: python, floating-point, addition

```
float(time)
if time == '90.00':
    added = added.getText()
    if not added == '':
        added = added.replace(':', '.')
        added = added.replace('+', '')
        added = ' '.join(added.split())
        float(added)
        time1 = time+added
        print time1
```

From football matches, trying to add 'injury time' to 90 mins.  Any idea why this isn't working.  I just get them both printing side by side a la

```
90.005.25
```

I think I am being dumb, have been staring at this for too long.

Thanks

Evan

Comment: The code is adding *strings* - this is common *string concatenation* behavior. The general solution is to convert the strings to numbers and *then* add them.

Comment: sorry, thanks for editing for me.

Comment: i thought float(added) and float(time) had converted them to floating points..?

Comment: `float(x)` does not change x. It returns y. Use y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if time == '90.00':
    time = float(time)
    added = added.getText()
    if not added == '':
        added = added.replace(':', '.')
        added = added.replace('+', '')
        added = ' '.join(added.split())
        added = float(added)
        time1 = time+added
        print time1
```

`float` is not an in place operation, `float(added)` returns `added` converted to a float, but does not changed `added`.  You do not save the returned value, so it goes off to the ether, and `added` is still a string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't adding numbers, you're adding strings. In Python, applying the + operator to strings concatenates them:

```
>>> 12 + 34
46
>>> '12' + '34'
'1234'
>>> 'Hello ' + 'world!'
'Hello world!'
```

@tcaswell already provided a fix using float instead of string addition.

Another option would be to use time module. Tthe advantage of this would be that there are built-in functions for doing things like converting seconds to minutes to hours and so forth.